# VB skipping lines while reading in text file

Tags: java, vb.net, text, readline, skip

i wrote a small text file parser in java and i need to redo it in Visual Basic so the simple exe can be moved from PC to PC.

i am having trouble getting VB 2010 express to omit lines with keywords.

here is the java that worked

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("/Users/leighlarue/Desktop/9-18-13.cap")));
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("ALL|MESSAGE|Time|PAPER_MAIN|paper_proc|IOMASTER|Options:|ERROR|Message|BAD GAUGE|Errors|GSP");
            if (pattern.matcher(line).find()) {
                continue;
            }
            stringBuffer.append(line);
            stringBuffer.append("\n");
        }

        BufferedWriter bwr = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("/Users/leighlarue/Desktop/Stage_One.txt")));

        bwr.write(stringBuffer.toString());

        bwr.flush();

        bwr.close();
        //System.out.println(stringBuffer);

    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
}
```

}

Can someone help me convert this to Visual Basic please?

what i am trying...

```
 Dim strFile As String = TextBox1.Text

    ' open file into stream reader
    Dim sr As New StreamReader(strFile)
    Dim line As String
    ' get the first line
    While sr.Peek <> -1
        line = sr.ReadLine()
        If line.Contains("MESSAGE") Then
            Continue While
        End If
        RichTextBox1.Text += line + CtrlChars.CrLf
        '    lineRead = sr.ReadLine()
    End While

End Sub
```

Comment: Use Regex, which will allow you to define a pattern much more in line with what you're doing in Java.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [RegularExpressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx) to replace Pattern.

```
' This can be initialized outside your loop
Dim regex As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("ALL|MESSAGE|Time|PAPER_MAIN|paper_proc|IOMASTER|Options:|ERROR|Message|BAD GAUGE|Errors|GSP")

If regex.Matches(line).Count > 0 Then
    Continue While
End If
```

Comment: i changed the code and it appears to work, but once the data is in the richtextbox the program is locked up, and the vshost32.exe is not responding under task manager. any ideas?

Comment: @DanielLaRue really hard to tell... do you have a lot of data?

Comment: yeah, i think that was the problem, it did finish when i let it run. i ended up making the richtextbox not visible and at the end of the if statement set it to visible, and it still took ~1 min to parse.

Comment: @DanielLaRue that's a long time. I would suggest you put all your strings in a StringBuilder and only at the end put the result in the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Dim strFile As String = TextBox1.Text

    ' open file into stream reader
    Dim sr As New StreamReader(strFile)
    Dim line As String
    ' get the first line
    While sr.Peek <> -1
        line = sr.ReadLine()
        If not line.Contains("MESSAGE") Then
            RichTextBox1.Text += line + CtrlChars.CrLf
' Or better yet, use a StringBuilder object.
        End If
    End While

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't see how this answer the question

Comment: Can you add more details to your answer to clearly illustrate the differences between this answer and the original question?